# Printing float values with sprintf

Tags: php, floating-point, numbers, printf

Right now I have:

`printf('Rating: %.2F', $rating);`

which prints like:

`4.00`

How can I show the leading zero, only if there is something to show after it?

For example:

- 4.00 should be 4
- 4.20 should be 4.2
- 4.02 should be 4.02 :)

Comment: A `float` doesn't really have precision per se (eg: a 32-bit IEEE-754 float has 23 bits of mantissa), it's up to you to determine what that is. Also please note that `4.00`, `4.0` and `4` mean different things. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures

Comment: why do you talk about sprintf in the title and you use printf?

Comment: The original I gave was based on formatting with a *leading* zero (as you stated above) -- but it seems like you actually want to suppress *trailing* zeroes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
printf("Rating: %g\n", 4.00);
printf("Rating: %g\n", 4.20);
printf("Rating: %g\n", 4.02);
```

prints

```
Rating: 4
Rating: 4.2
Rating: 4.02
```

So will printing the values without `printf`

[demo](http://codepad.org/ZA1mk3yn)

Comment: While this is what the OP asked, it really bothers me to see a complete disregard for the concept of significant figures. 4 and 4.00 are not the same. Aaaaaaaaaaaargh